# Immutable folder (css, js, assets) not found when executing build version on a server (adapter-node)

Tags: sveltekit

I'm trying to run a build version of a simple sveltekit app and discovered that the immutable folder is not found (on the rendered page) with all the assets and js files when running on the server, just a 404.

I'm using the default project structure with default settings without changing anything in svelte.config

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
   kit: {
      adapter: adapter()
   }
};

export default config;
```

My _app path on the server is `/var/www/websitename.com/html/build/client/_app/`

The webpage is being rendered with these paths for assets (actually not found), since `/build/` directory is missing.

```
<link href="./_app/immutable/assets/_page-357a2d4f.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./_app/immutable/assets/navbar-d4dfc8fc.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I found that the correct location for an immutable folder should be rendered like this:

`href="./build/_app/immutable/assets/_page-357a2d4f.css"`

I tried adding the `out` option to the adapter parameters. That doesn't help either.

```
adapter: adapter({ out: 'build' })
```

Comment: And again, locally `npm run dev` or `npm run preview` works fine as expected while browser still requesting immutable folder without `/build/` in its path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The mistake was in the apache2 proxy config, the IP address where nodejs is running `http://0.0.0.0:3000` missed `/` at the end

```
   <Location />
          ProxyPass http://0.0.0.0:3000/
          ProxyPassReverse http://0.0.0.0:3000/
   </Location>
```